# how to get all values from an multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hai first take a look at this array,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [parent_id] => 3
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 7
                            [parent_id] => 4
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 6
                                            [parent_id] => 7
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 2
                                                            [parent_id] => 6
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [parent_id] => 3
        )

)
```

i need a output of all id [IE: 4, 7, 6, 2, 5] was the desired result
i need something like

```
foreach ($tree as $j) {
    echo $j['id'];
    if($j['children']){

    }
```

but how to loop it out to get all the child's? i am not able to catch all the child elements or else i am getting strucked onto an infinite loop is how to get the desired result in php? any suggestions will be really appreciated!

Comment: You could play with http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656682/getting-all-children-for-a-deep-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($input, function($value, $key) use(&$result) {
    if ($key === 'id') {
        $result[] = $value;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use a recursive function like:

```
function getIds($tree) {
        foreach ($tree as $j) {
            echo $j['id'];
            if(isset($j['children'])){
                getIds($j['children']);
            }
        }
    }
```

And in the main just need:

```
getIds($tree);
```